# Accessing a database located on another computer using PHP

Tags: php, local, schedule

My client has an offline product database for a high street shop that they update fairly frequently for their own purposes. They are now creating an online store which they want to use product information from this database.

Migrating the database to a hosted server and abandoning the offline database is not an option due to their current legacy software set up.

So my question is: how can I get the information from their offline database to an online database? Their local server is always connected to the internet so is it possible to create a script on the website that somehow grabs the data from their server and imports it into the online server? If this ran every 24 hours it would be perfect. But is it even possible? And if so how would I do it?

The only other option I can think of is to manually upload the database after every update, but this isn't really a viable idea.

Comment: What format is the local database? What OS does the local system use?

Comment: The local system is windows, and uses Visual Foxpro (don't know which version sorry)

Comment: It depends on what database system is being used. Its possible you could do some sort of replication if supported. Otherwise you will end up less real time and have to sync changes with cron.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something like this with quickbooks using an odbc connection. Using that I synced data to MySQL. This synchronization however, was just one way. Unless you have keys in the data that indicates when something was changed (updated date), you will end up syncing alot of extra data.

Using SQLYog, i set up a scheduled job that connected to the odbc data source, and pushed the changes since last sync to the mysql database I was using to generate reports. If you can get the data replicated into MySQL it should be easy at that point to make use of it in your online store.

The downside is that it wont be realtime. Inventory could become a problem.

Answer (score 1):

In an ideal world I would look at creating a restful API that would run on the same server or at least run on the same network as your offline database.  This restful API would run as  a web server via http and return JSON or even XML structures of data from the offline database. Clients running on the internet would be able to connect and fetch any data they need, at any time. A restful API like this has a number of advantages.

Firstly it's secure.  You don't have to open up an attack vector to the public by making connections to your offline database public.  The only thing you have to do is enable public access to your restful API.  In your API's logic you might not even include functionality to write to the database so even if your API's security is compromised at very worst all attackers can do is read your data, not corrupt it.

Having a restful api in this situation represents a good separation of concerns.  Your client code should not know anything about the database nor should it know about any internal systems that the offline database uses. What happens when your clients want to update their offline system or even change it?  In this situation all you would have to do is update the restful api. Your client that is connecting to the data no longer cares about anything else but the api so changing databases would be easy.

Another reason to consider an API is concurrency.  I hinted at this before but having an API would be great if you ever need to have more than one client accessing the offline databases' data. In a web server set up where you would have the API sitting and waiting for requests there is no reason why you could not have more  than one client connecting to the api at the same time. HTTP is really good at this!

You talked about having to place old data in a new database. Something like this could be done easily with a restful API as you would just have to map the endpoints of your API to tables in the new database and run that when you need. You could even forgo the new database and use the API as your backend. This solution would require some caching but it would cut down on the duplication of a database if you don't feel it's needed.

The draw back to all of this is the fact that writing an API over a script is more complex. So in this situation I believe in horses for courses. If this database is the backbone of a long term project that will be expanding in the future an API is the way to go.  If its a small part of your project then maybe you can swing it with a script that runs every 24 hours however I have done this before and the second I have to change/edit the solution things start getting a little "hairy". Hope this helps and good luck with it.